# What's the meaning of "with a quarter in the frame"?

Tags: meaning

When it comes to picture or camera, what's the meaning of **with a quarter in the frame**?

For example, picture **with a quarter in the frame**.

The original video clip is [Here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mlUsyQzJAHI&t=8s) at 0:32

Sorry for that I couldn't transcript the diologs because the contents is quite naughty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The words following your excerpt add a lot of meaning:

> ... with a quarter in the frame to show its size

The speaker is suggesting that the listener include a US 25¢ coin (a quarter) in the frame (of the picture) as a reference for scale.

See http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=890718 and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35555375/measure-size-of-object-using-reference-object-in-photo